# Unity Ball moving inside the surface

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine

I have created Simple golf game. In this game my ball sometimes goes inside the surface. I used the Mesh collider for objects except ball.

How do I avoid the ball going inside of the surface while playing?

Comment: Does your ball have a sphere collider? How are you moving your ball? with rigidbody or with transform.translate?